# Configuro las claves SSH en un servidor y sigue pidiendo la contraseña, cuando lo hago en sentido contrario sí funciona correctamente

Tags: ssh

Tengo dos servidores, uno de NFS  el otro un openmediavault que hace el backup. Necesito que el OMV se conecte sin contraseña al NFS para hacer dicho backup.

Genero las claves desde el OMV con:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Luego copio la clave mediante:

```
ssh-copy-id user@x.x.x.x
```

No me da ningún error pero al intentar conectar sigue pidiendo la clave.

Cuando hago el procedimiento en sentido inverso, es decir, desde el NFS al OMV si funciona sin problemas.

En un sentido funciona, pero en el inverso no.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:e2zIn1gfBWhUtvfcLeVEhgVLotiFq0V4V7duo4tD+7M root@nfs
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|         ..o=.++=|
|        .++=.+.=.|
|        .o=oo o.o|
|         .o  o.*o|
|        So    o+*|
|       ..+ . .o..|
|        + * o.   |
|         * =.o.  |
|        . o.+Eo  |
+----[SHA256]-----+
root@nfs:~# ssh-copy-id root@192.168.0.8
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out 
any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted 
now it is to install the new keys
root@192.168.0.8's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'root@192.168.0.8'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

¿Qué puede estar pasando? La conexión sin contraseña funcionaba hasta que dejó de funcionar y ya no sé qué más hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta los siguientes comandos en el servidor de (NFS), es decir en el servidor donde copiaste la copiaste la llave SSH.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```